# GridView Selection Mode

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

I am working on windows store application in Which I set the selection mode to "SINGLE" but by default first item on the grid view is selected. The Item has to be selected only when we right tapped.

```
         <local:MyGridView x:Name="itemGridView" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"           SelectionMode="Single" RightTapped="AppBar"  AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Grouped Items"  >
```

Comment: what is your actual question?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the SelectedItem attribute to null?